# Setting a firestore document when a new user is created with firebase auth using node.js

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firebase cloud functions, firebase auth and firestore.
I've done this before with firebase database but just not sure with firestore how to set a document in the users collection to the uid of a newly created firebase auth user.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore()

exports.createUser  = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

 const uid  = event.data.uid;
 console.log(uid);

 db.collection('users').doc(uid);


});
```

The above completes ok in the logs but the uid isn't getting set in the database. Do I need to call set at some stage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const collection = db.collection("users")
const userID = "12345" // ID after created the user.
collection.doc(userID).set({
    name : "userFoo", // some another information for user you could save it here.
    uid : userID     // you could save the ID as field in document.
}).then(() => {
    console.log("done")
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Note, that the `onCreate` return has changed, it does return the user now, so `event.data.uid` isn't valid anymore.

The full function should look something like this, it will create a document with the user's `uid` in the "users" root-collection.

```js
exports.createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const { uid } = user;

    const userCollection = db.collection('users');

    userCollection.doc(uid).set({
        someData: 123,
        someMoreData: [1, 2, 3],
    });
});
```

Comment: make sure to make the function passed to ```onCreate``` an ```async``` function, and to ```await``` when setting the document, as ```set``` returns a promise